# Need Assistance With Batch File: Detecting Folders on Exhisting Drives

Tags: windows, batch-file, drive

I've been working on a batch file to search for a folder and if it exhist do a goto command with that variable. It works, but every time you get spammed with:
"There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive to \device\hardisk1\dr21 and so on. Is there a way I can prevent this message from popping up?

Batch File:

```
@echo off
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion


for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
if exist %%d:\custom\ (
  ECHO Device Found : %%d
  )
)
```

Comment: However right now it's just set to echo rather than goto, for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Vague title is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Weird. It works for me on Windows 7 with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're calling this from the command line then going:

```
batch.bat arguments 2> NUL
```

will redirect all error messages to the `NUL` device, which will prevent them from popping up.

or create a wrapper subroutine within the batch file itself, for example:

```
@echo off
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion

CALL :SUB_A 2> NUL
GOTO :EOF

:SUB_A
for %%d in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    if exist %%d:\custom\ (
      ECHO Device Found : %%d
    )
)
GOTO:EOF
```

will not return an error because the subroutines error messages are going to `NUL`

Comment: It's a window that pops up, not a line in cmd.

Comment: @KaveElite Hmm this script works perfectly for me on my computer, this is pure guesswork but you may need to un-map then re-map your drives to stop that message.